# how to get the value from three tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have 3 tables. like :`B001,B002,B003`.

Every table has `Entrynumber` column.

So I have to find `Entrynumber` value is exist or not in all 3 tables.

Like we write for one table :

```
select count(*) from B001  Where Entrynumber ='3340'
```

I want to know that what is the best way to join the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use an inner join

```
select count(*) 
from B001 b1
inner join B002 b2 on b1.Entrynumber = b2.Entrynumber 
inner join B003 b3 on b1.Entrynumber = b3.Entrynumber 
Where b1.Entrynumber ='3340'
```

to get the number of records where `Entrynumber` exists in all tables.

Answer (score 0):

To find the value in all tables

```
 select
      (select count(*) from b001 where EntryNumber = '3340') b1Count,
      (select count(*) from b002 where EntryNumber = '3340') b2Count,
      (select count(*) from b003 where EntryNumber = '3340') b3Count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B001
INNER JOIN B002 ON (B001.Entrynumber = B002.Entrynumber AND B002.Entrynumber = '3340')
INNER JOIN B003 ON (B001.Entrynumber = B003.Entrynumber AND B003.Entrynumber = '3340')
WHERE B001.Entrynumber = '3340'
```

Inner join with where condition is best way.